# What does it mean to be a function of something?

Tags: functions

There is a sentence in Sokal and Rohlf's classic text [[R.R.Sokal F.J.Rohlf; Biometry, 3rd ed., 1994](http://www.whfreeman.com/Catalog/product/biometry-thirdedition-sokal): p.132, chapter 7 *Estimation and Hypothesis Testing*]:

> The variance of means is therefore partly a function of the sample
>   size on which the means are based.

In this specific case, I understand that the greater the sample size the lesser the standard deviation of sample means. But in general what does it mean to be a function of something? Relationship or dependence?

(Please provide answers/comments in plain language.)

Answer (score 5):

"$A$ is partly a function of $B$" means that if you change $B$, even if you don't change anything else, the chances are that $A$ will also change.

Comment: Unless the function is constant, of course :-)

Comment: @Sim, if $A$ is constant, Sokal et al would not write $A$ is partly a function of $B$ --- and you know it --- so why confuse OP?

Comment: @Siminore That is what the phrase "chances are" is there for.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You should know that constant functions are functions. By the the way, a function is something that must be defined without any reference to "chances", "good luck" or equivalent words.

Comment: @Siminore, you should know that a teacher answers a question using language the student can be expected to understand.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, but we are currently living in 2012. Functions are no longer "dark things", nowadays. And, sincerely, a teacher should answer correctly, no matter how difficult the answer is. Here it is clear that the authors of that book use an old-fashioned language, which has almost nothing to do with mathematics. Everything is a function of everything, you know.

Comment: @Siminore, let me encourage you to post your own answer to stan's question.

Comment: Well, as a mathematician I should say that the sentence has no meaning at all. Period. It is a vague sentence that the authors write to do some "conversation", or probably (I cannot find the book in my library) to use scientific words and pave the way to a mathematical model.

Comment: @Siminore, good. Post that as an answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson - quick question, when authors say something like “the  position of a ball is a function of time”, is it correct to think about this mathematically as: we’re considering a function $f$ such that $f(t)$ is interpreted to be *the position of the ball at time $t$*?

Comment: @Taylor, yes, that would be how I would interpret it.

Answer (score 5):

In layman terms as requested, a function takes input values and gives output values. It is like a blender. Put in apples and we get apple juice. Put in orange and we get orange juice. In your context, it means that the variance depends on sample size, just like what juice you get depends on what fruits you throw in!